# logstash elasticsearch unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

[image: kopf dashboard]

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it:

Note that the first logstash index which has all shards assigned is only in that state because I manually assigned them.

Everything had been working as expected for several months until just today I noticed that shards have been laying around unassigned on all my logstash indexes.

Using Elasticsearch v1.4.0

My Elasticsearch logs appear as follows up until July 29, 2015:

```
[2015-07-29 00:01:53,352][DEBUG][discovery.zen.publish    ] [Thor] received cluster state version 4827
```

Also, there is a script running on the server which trims the number of logstash indexes down to 30. I think that is where this type of log line comes from:

```
[2015-07-29 17:43:12,800][DEBUG][gateway.local.state.meta ] [Thor] [logstash-2015.01.25] deleting index that is no longer part of the metadata (indices: [[kibana-int, logstash-2015.07.11, logstash-2015.07.04, logstash-2015.07.03, logstash-2015.07.12, logstash-2015.07.21, logstash-2015.07.17, users_1416418645233, logstash-2015.07.20, logstash-2015.07.25, logstash-2015.07.06, logstash-2015.07.28, logstash-2015.01.24, logstash-2015.07.18, logstash-2015.07.26, logstash-2015.07.08, logstash-2015.07.19, logstash-2015.07.09, logstash-2015.07.22, logstash-2015.07.07, logstash-2015.07.29, logstash-2015.07.10, logstash-2015.07.05, logstash-2015.07.01, logstash-2015.07.16, logstash-2015.07.24, logstash-2015.07.02, logstash-2015.07.27, logstash-2015.07.14, logstash-2015.07.13, logstash-2015.07.23, logstash-2015.06.30, logstash-2015.07.15]])
```

On July 29, there are a few new entries which I haven't seen before:

```
[2015-07-29 00:01:38,024][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Thor] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
[2015-07-29 17:12:58,658][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Thor] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.enable] from [ALL] to [NONE]
[2015-07-29 17:12:58,658][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Thor] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disable_allocation] from [false] to [true]
```

Comment: have you checked your elasticsearch logs?

Comment: I guess some node may went down for some time.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information I've gathered from my elasticsearch log files.